# How to pass a newline character in Redis with Lua script

Tags: lua, redis, newline

I set records in Redis database with a Lua script.
Some records may contain newline characters.
How can I set a new record with body containing a newline character using Lua?

My code is:

```
redis.call("set", "text", "First line\nSecond line" );
```

But when I examine this record in redis-cli> get "text", I'd like it to be:

```
First line
Second line
```

But I get:

```
First line\nSecond line
```

Comment: I use redis-cli> get "text"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text is being stored as expected, literally.  If you want to store the formatted string you need to do just that

```
redis.call("set", "text", string.format("First line\nSecond line") );
```

Comment: I've done redis.call("set", "text", string.format("First line\nSecond line") ); but get text gives First line\nSecond line. But I need to have a newline character to be in this record (insted of 2 symbols '\' and 'n' I need one symbol that is a newline symbol)

Comment: Thanks, now I understand that it's just redis-cli who prints "\n" symbols instead of printing text on the new line

Comment: @Ivan that's right, if you want you can turn it off w the `--raw` switch